# How to bind a ReadOnlyCollection<T> to DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, binding

I am working with a Schneider product called [ClearSCADA](http://software.schneider-electric.com/products/clearscada/) that allows you to query its proprietary backend database through a .Net interface. I have successfully queried the DB using this query:

```
    SELECT
        "Id", "FullName", "Foreground", "Blink", "Background", "TypeDesc", "MemoryUsage"
    FROM
        "CCustomColour"
    ORDER BY
        "FullName" ASC
```

and have results returned to me as a QueryResult:

```
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

    namespace ClearScada.Client.Advanced
    {
        //
        public class QueryResult
        {
            //
            // Summary:
            //     Gets the results of the query.
            public ReadOnlyCollection<QueryRow> Rows { get; }
            //
            // Summary:
            //     Gets the number of rows affected for a DML query.
            public int RowsAffected { get; }
            //
            // Summary:
            //     Gets the status of the query.
            public QueryStatus Status { get; }
        }
    }
```

I have tried to bind the [ReadOnlyCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474(v=vs.110).aspx) of rows to the datagrid a couple of different ways.

```
   dataGridViewResults.DataSource = this.MyQueryResult.Rows;
```

and

```
                BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
                bs.DataSource = this.MyQueryResult.Rows;
                dataGridViewResults.DataSource = bs;
```

The grid shows me a single column showing only the row index but no data:

[image]

For reference here is the definition of the QueryRow class:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace ClearScada.Client.Advanced
{
    //
    public class QueryRow
    {
        //
        public ReadOnlyCollection<object> Data { get; }
        //
        public int Index { get; }
    }
}
```

I created a local copy of my QueryResult instance so that I could capture a view of it in the 'Locals' window in Visual Studio to show here:

[image: View of the QueryResult in the 'Locals' window of Visual Studio]

What I am trying to achieve is a view that displays like this:

[image]

Can you please help me by showing me how I can bind those values to the DataGridView?

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there must be a better way but this is working for me by transferring the data to a DataTable and then binding that to the DataGridView:

```
                if (this.MyQueryStatus.Equals(QueryStatus.Succeeded))
                {
                    #region IF Succeeded
                    #region Create Results DataTable
                    DataTable resultsTable = new DataTable("Results");
                    resultsTable.Columns.Add("Id");
                    resultsTable.Columns.Add("FullName");
                    resultsTable.Columns.Add("Foreground");
                    resultsTable.Columns.Add("Blink");
                    resultsTable.Columns.Add("Background");
                    resultsTable.Columns.Add("TypeDesc");
                    resultsTable.Columns.Add("MemoryUsage");
                    #endregion Create Results DataTable

                    foreach (var row in this.MyQueryResult.Rows)
                    {
                        #region ForEach Row
                        DataRow newRow = resultsTable.NewRow();
                        newRow["Id"] = row.Data[0].ToString();
                        newRow["FullName"] = row.Data[1].ToString();
                        newRow["Foreground"] = row.Data[2].ToString();
                        newRow["Blink"] = row.Data[3].ToString();
                        newRow["Background"] = row.Data[4].ToString();
                        newRow["TypeDesc"] = row.Data[5].ToString();
                        newRow["MemoryUsage"] = row.Data[6].ToString();
                        resultsTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
                        #endregion ForEach Row
                    }

                    dataGridViewResults.DataSource = resultsTable;
                    tabControlMain.SelectedTab = tabControlMain.TabPages["tabPageResults"];
                    #endregion IF Succeeded
                }
```

I would still be grateful if someone can explain how to bind the ReadOnlyCollection directly to the DataGridView.

Comment: Have you tried `dataGridViewResults.DataSource = this.MyQueryResult.Rows.ToList()`?

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I just tried to implement this but 'this.MyQueryResult.Rows' does not have a ToList method. It only exposes 2 methods, CopyTo and ToString. The CopyTo method allows the ReadOnlyCollection of Rows to be copied to an array of QueryRow objects. I tried this and then looked for a ToList method on the resulting array but again it did not have a ToList method.

Comment: What about a List constructor instead of a straight conversion? `List<MyQueryResults> mqr = new List<MyQueryResults>(this.MyQueryResults);`?

Comment: Thanks, tried this but no joy, the error text is 'Argument 1: cannot convert from 'ClearSCADA.Client.Advanced.QueryResult' to int'. The constructor has 3 signatures 'List<QueryResult>()', 'List<QueryResult>(int capacity)', 'List<QueryResult>(IEnumerable<QueryResult> collection)'.

Comment: So I then tried List<QueryResults> mqr = new List<QueryResults>(this.MyQueryResults.Rows); since Rows is defined as System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<QueryRow>. Seemed to be a no brainer (to me), I then get the error 'Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<ClearSCADA.Client.Advanced.QueryResult>' to int'. I am out of my depth and this confuses me since it seems to match the third signature: 'List<QueryResult>(IEnumerable<QueryResult> collection)'. I remain confused by this.